# WordPress, retrieving the ID of the user profile page currently being edited

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm in the process of developing a WordPress plugin.  When editing a user's profile page, I need to be able to retrieve the ID of that user (*not the currently logged in user*).

I'm using the Advanced Custom fields plugin, and using a load filter for the function in question.

```
add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=funbotic_parents', 'funbotic_load_parents' );

function funbotic_load_parents( $field ) {

    $args = array(
        'role'      => 'customer',
        'orderby'   => 'display_name',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
    );

    $parent_data_array = get_users( $args );

    // Clear choices array in case it was previously set.
    $field['choices'] = array();

    foreach ( $parent_data_array as $parent ) {
        $parent_ID = $parent->ID;
        $parent_display_name = $parent->display_name;
        $field['choices'][$parent_ID] = $parent_display_name;
    }

    $current_user = (int) $_GET['user_id'];

    $previously_associated_parents = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'funbotic_parents' );

    if ( empty( $previously_associated_parents ) || is_null( $previously_associated_parents ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'funbotic_previously_associated_parents', $previously_associated_parents );
    } else {
        $new_meta = funbotic_clean_array( $previously_associated_parents );
        update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'funbotic_previously_associated_parents', $new_meta );
    }

    return $field;

}
```

The line `$current_user = (int) $_GET['user_id'];` is returning `null`.  Is there a way to pull 'user_id' from the URL?  It's not an ideal solution but at this point I'm starting to get desperate.  The URL looks like this:

```
http://dev-funbotic.local/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=115&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php%3Fs%3Dtest%26action%3D-1%26new_role%26course_id%26group_id%26paged%3D1%26action2%3D-1%26new_role2
```

Comment: You can refer the asnwers given on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69461/how-to-obtain-the-user-id-of-the-current-profile-being-edited-in-wp-admin

Comment: This is one of the first things I discovered upon searching for answers.  The reason I posted this question is because none of those solutions mentioned in that thread, or any other thread I've found, have solved this issue.  As I mentioned in my post, $_GET['user_id'] returns a null value.  And attempting to access $user_id as a global variable is also unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the current url and breaking it down to query params like this:

```
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
                $params = array();
                if(!empty($query[0])){
                    foreach( $query as $param ){
                    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
                    $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
                    }
                }
```

then you can access the user_id by `$params['user_id'][0]`

Comment: I appreciate the feedback - it turns out that part of the problem here is that WordPress uses AJAX when editing user profiles.  So $params[2] ends up being a null string.  I'm continuing to investigate how to reference the AJAX-generated URL, but no luck yet.